# How to represent a variable key name in typescript interface?

Tags: typescript, interface

```
interface Items {
    id: Item,
}
```

id is not optional but it will have different name

for example:

```
let items = {
34433ded : {name: "foo", price: 0.99},
14d433dee : {name: "bar", price: 1.99},
}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Something like:

```
interface Item {
    name: string;
    price: string;
}

type Items = { [id: string]: Item }

let items = {
    34433ded : {name: "foo", price: 0.99},
    14d433dee : {name: "bar", price: 1.99},
} as Items;
```

Answer (score 22):

You can achive this by following structure:

```
interface Items {
    [key: string]: Item;
}
```

Here is your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z5kc2ud7/).
But remember due to JSON specification your object keys should't begin with numbers or if they do - you have to wrap them in quotes (as I did in fiddle)